# How do you visualise a subspace of 2 by 2 matrices(and higher up, 3 by 3 etc)

Tags: linear-algebra

If a subspace is a linear combination of some vectors, how can a subspace of matrices(which act to stretch a space) exist?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to ask here. Subspace of matrices is kind of an incomplete sentence. When you refer to a subspace, you need to say a subspace of what? It is easy to prove that the set $M_{nn}$ i.e all the square matrices, is a subspace of the set $M_{nm}$ i.e all the matrices (under the same field at least).

Comment: I personally visualize $\mathbb{R}^3$, then repeatedly say under my breath "this is a space of matrices. this is a space of matrices". I know this isn't necessarily helpful, but for almost all matrix spaces, this is basically the best we can do.

Comment: @Eminem how about just the vector space of 2x2 matrices? Not really looking for a specific context, more of just spaces involving matrices in general

Comment: Matrices are a sort of vector. Writing the component in a $2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3$ grid instead of as a single row or column is immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

$m\times n$-matrices with coefficients in a field $K$ form a $K$-vectorspace. You can add and subtract them componentwise and you have a multiplication with scalars in $K$ (again componentwise). These two operations can be easily checked to satisfy the axioms of a $K$-vectorspace. Moreover the matrices with a 1 in exactly one entry can be seen to form a basis, so we immediately get that $\operatorname{Mat}_{m,n}(K)$ is $mn$-dimensional.

Any vector space has subspaces. The easiest one being the zero subspace. If your vector space has dimension $\geq 2$, then any single nonzero vector generates a nontrivial subspace of dimension 1. So in particular for $mn\geq 2$ we can choose a nontrivial matrix (ie a vector in the vector space of matrices) and get a subspace of matrices out of it.

As $mn\geq 4$ rather easily we find that visualizing subspaces of matrices is rather difficult. I don’t know if anyone can really visualize anything of dimension $>4$. It is common to think of it like it would be 3-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

This is why the abstraction  provided by algebraic structures is useful.

The "vectors" of a vector space $E$ need not be actual, geometric vectors (as in $\vec{AB}$ is a vector of $\mathbb R^2$). Saying that $E$ is a vector space (say with underlying field $\mathbb R$) simply means that you have some operation $+$ in $E$, some neutral element $0 \in E$, that you can multiply elements of $E$ by any real number $\lambda$ ... and a bunch of other properties.

We do not care what the elements of $E$ actually *are*: number, matrices, functions, matrices of functions acting on polynomial on some finite field ... who cares ? This is the power that algebra provides, as long as your space satisfies this set of axioms, then all the theorems apply without ever having to look at what you are actually applying them to.

This allows you to *think* about any (finite dimensional) vector space as $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$ (in order to get good *intuitions* - obviously, this is not a rigorous visualisation ...) and make conjectures, observations ... that might be true just because you are in a vector space. This is because what matters is the *structure*, the relations between the points, not the actual points of the space.

Obviously, a lot of questions are specific to some vector spaces, but some of them are really about the structure of the space ... in which case you don't even need to know what you are working with, the fact that you have a vector space means that you can think of it as $\mathbb R^2$, get an easy intuition on how things work, and immediately transpose it to the general setting.

Comment: I see. So moving forward, I should try to not rely on literally visualizing what's going on in LA? More of perhaps using a 2/3d space to first understand the concept, then moving on without relying on such visualizations.

Comment: Yeah. For example, consider the notion of orthogonality. If you are working with matrices ... how the hell do you *see* orthogonal subspaces of matrices ?! Well, you don't. You just imagine a plane in $\mathbb R^3$, a line that is orthogonal to it, and now you can actually think about your problem ! You can *visualize* what projections on those orthogonal spaces do, understand what the scalar product would be, and so on, without actually thinking about ... orthogonal *matrices* at any point !